# Unable to install postgreSQL 9.6 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, postgresql

I'm trying to install postgreSQL 9.6 in Ubuntu 18.04 via Ubuntu Software Centre and type from terminal

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6`

according to official documentation https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

```
Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list and add a line for the repository
```

> deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main

```
Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc |   sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

[The version to be installaed is 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3RO8.png)

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

```
postgresql:
```

Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10+191.pgdg18.04+1
  Version table:
     10+191.pgdg18.04+1 500
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main i386 Packages
     10+190 500
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages

If I check where are the postgresql folders, it seems that I have both versions, 9.6 and 10

[/usr/lib/postgresql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yumR8.png)

Comment: I don't think you can install version 9.6 from Ubuntu Software, so you need to add a repository. You have included the exact instructions to do so: 1) create a file containing one line of text, then 2) import a key using the `wget` command. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @Jos after I typed sudo apt-cache policy postgresql, it appears the the response I've attached above

Comment: It seems that you have successfully installed version 9.6. Now it's a good idea to remove version 10 with `sudo apt remove postgresql-10`.

Comment: @Jos I have removed postgres 10, following the command you suggest and then I ran sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6, the folder 9.6 appears in /usr/lib/postgresql, however, when I type in terminal sudo apt-cache policy postgresql, it says there is no postgresql installed. postgresql:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10+191.pgdg18.04+1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After few months I had to erase and install from scratch, so in order to install postgresql 9.6 I followed next steps:

**Important notes**: If you have already installed postgresql 10 and you want 9.6, you need to remove postgresql 10 completely and then manually install postgresql 9.6, so follow **method 2**.

**Method 1**

Step 1

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Step 2

```
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Step 3.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

**Method 2**

In order to install postgres 9.6 having already postgres 10 or other version different from 9.6 installed, you need first to uninstall postgresql (any version and file related) completely following the next steps.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql

dpkg -l | grep postgres (to look for postgresfiles in the system)

sudo rm -rf postgresql ... (remove all the files that appeared in the list after running the previous command)
```

Finally install manually postgreSQL with the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

I hope it can help somebody that could have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely the same in my case when trying to replace *postgresql 10* with *postgresql 9.4*.

I removed the old unwanted packages by

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs sudo apt --purge remove -y
```

But while I am trying to remove the packages, I also encounter several issues, I **terminate** the process before it reaches the *100%* and the following commands are used to fix the issues along the way.

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

sudo kill -9 <PID>

sudo dpkg --configure -a

# if necessary, rerun the removing command above
```

And start the installation as:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-9.4
```