# What's the difference between psql -V and apt-cache policy postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgres 9.6, If you type in terminal psql -V  or psql --version, you know which postgresql version you have installed, however, if you type sudo apt-cache policy postgresql, it appears that you do not have installed postgresql and that the candidate is postgresql 10.

Do you know why this last command does not recognize postgres 9.6 install and which is the difference?

Thanks is advance

Comment: How did you install postgres 9.6? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: `apt-cache` looks at actual package containing an app and things, it doesn't search by "app name". Package names often have a version attached to it.  So try `apt-cache policy postgresql9` or `postgresql9.6`

Comment: @steeldriver, I did it with sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6, I had a problem installing this specific version with 18.04, I asked to the community, I found the solution, removing completety the postgres 10 In this link you can check the steps in case you have a similar issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052079/unable-to-install-postgresql-9-6-in-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment1718906_1052079

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy thanks for your time, however, I have a message "unable to locate package posgresql9 or 9.6" when typing the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, `apt-cache policy <package name>` asks `apt-get` to shows the package information, while `psql -V` makes the postgres itself report the version. So `postgresql-9.6` is the package that contains the actual app and related files, among which `psql`. Either one is valid, but in case of `apt-cache` you need to provide the name of the actual package you've installed, while app or command might be different as in `psql` case.

As mentioned in the comments as well, you've installed the package as `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6`, and same name should be used with `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy postgresql-9.6
postgresql-9.6:
  Installed: 9.6.3-4+b1
  Candidate: 9.6.3-4+b1
  Version table:
 *** 9.6.3-4+b1 500
<removed sources>
```